# Loop through few Azure subscriptions (not all) in a Tenant using for each loop Powershell to fetch RG data

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am writing a Powershell script, where in when i create for each loop to fetch all RG data in Azure, it loops through all existing subscriptions in the Tenant, my requirment is to only select 3 out of 10 subscriptions in my Tenant.

Loop through few Azure subscriptions (not all) in a Tenant using for each loop Powershell to fetch RG data

Answer (score 0):

Look into the following cmdlets:

- Get-AzSubscription
- Select-AzSubscription
- Set-AzContext

these should help you.